# How can I open a c:// folder of file or documents in powerapps

Tags: powerapps

When a button is clicked (screen1) open in next (screen2)  a c: folder or map.

```
Navigate ()?
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigate() function can only take you to screens inside the app.  Because the same functionality is expected to work across web, iOS and Android, you can't directly open a local file location.

If you are looking to add a picture or a file, try using the Add picture or Attachments controls.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do to open a File upload control experience. `Insert - Media - Add picture`

[image]